# Getting events from other user calendar

Tags: kotlin, google-calendar-api

I'm building an app in Kotlin which will manage appointments between a service provider and a client(e.g. hair dresser). I want to read the events of the service provider has in his Google Calendar from the app of the client. i.e. The client wants to set an appointment, after he selects what he wants i want to give him a list of appoints availiable for that day and to that i need to get the events of the service proivder on that day/week/month.
How can I achieve that with Kotlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it no thanks to Google's documenation.

```
val user_email = "no_body@gmail.com"
const val READ_EVENTS_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
val appName = this.applicationInfo.packageName
var jsonPrivateKeyFile = resources.openRawResource(resources.getIdentifier("json_key", "raw", packageName)
GoogleCredential.fromStream(jsonPrivateKeyFile).createScoped(Collections.singleton(READ_EVENTS_SCOPE))
var builder = Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, getCredential())
builder.applicationName = appName
val GoogleCalendarAPI = builder.build()
val event_list = GoogleCalendarAPI?.events()?.list(user_email)
```

The events of the user will be in event_list.
Important things:

- In the user's gmail calendar, In the share part of the settings add the email of the service account you created.
- Add wide global delegation to the service account.
- The code below should be done inside a different thread than the GUI thread otherwise it will fail.

If someone has a probelm with the code above in Kotlin, hit me up and i'll help you gladly :-)